# Web method 404 not found after publishing to production server

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code is working perfecting after publishing to my localhost.  So I copied the files from my localhost and put them on the server.  Now it's saying it cannot find the web method.  The project is an MVC project and what's not working is an separate aspx page added to the project directory.  So, I don't know if this has something to do with IIS.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
     [WebMethod]
        public static string LoadPatients(string phone, string user)
        {
//SOME STUFF HERE THAT WAS EXCLUDED//
           var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (var x = 0; x < Callerdt.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                var addr = Callerdt.Rows[x]["Street"].ToString() + " " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["city"].ToString() + ", " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["State"].ToString() + " " + Callerdt.Rows[x]["ZipCode"].ToString();
                sb.AppendFormat("<div class='tabs'><table>" +
                                "<tr><td class='title'><label>Name:</label></td><td>{0}</td></tr>" +
                                "<tr><td><label>DOB:</label></td><td>{1}</td></tr>" +
                                "<tr><td><label>Address:</label></td><td>{2}</td></tr>" +
                                "<tr><td><label>SSN:</label></td><td>{3}</td></tr>" +
                                "<tr><td><label>Z Number:</label></td><td>{4}</td></tr>" +
                                "</table></div><br/>", Callerdt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString(), Callerdt.Rows[x]["DOB"].ToString(), addr, Callerdt.Rows[x]["SSN"].ToString(), Callerdt.Rows[x]["ZNUM"].ToString());
            }
            ret = sb.ToString();
            return ret;
        }





<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var p = document.getElementById('pn').value, u = document.getElementById('user').value, er = document.getElementById('error').value;
        if (!(er == "true")) {
            $("#loading").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CallerPopup.aspx/LoadPatients',
                data: JSON.stringify({ phone: p, user: u }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tabs').append(data.d);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have friendly URLs enabled?  I have this comment in my app:         ' Whatever you do, do not set AutoRedirectMode=RedirectMode.Permanent.  That will break the PageMethods call and the entire app will fail.

Comment: Hi Duston - This got it working. The problem was the routes, it was following the MVC routes and wasn't finding the page..Which would be as expected.  Thanks for replying!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683426/ajax-webmethod-call-returns-404-on-mvc3

Answer (score 2):

In my case, adding IgnoreRoute to RegisterRoutes() got me going.  Now the aspx.cs "static" hosted [webmethod] loads ... url: 'LearnKO.aspx/FetchStudents',

aJax was throwing a 404 - Not Found   on any page.aspx/webmethod call.

ie. the fix:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

I was setting up http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/learning-knockout-part-1-introduction-to-knockout-js-and-cr/  in an MVC project instead of the recommended empty ASP.NET...  my bad.

Comment: Thank you...@StevoKeano.. It is working. Thank you so much.